# How to update lambda@edge ARN in cloudfront distribution using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I would like to update the cloudfront distribution with the latest lambda@edge function using CLI.

I saw [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html), but could not figure out how to update the lambda ARN only.

Can some one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
CONFIG=$(aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id CGSKSKLSLSM)
ETAG=$(echo "${CONFIG}" | jq -r '.ETag')
echo "${CONFIG}" | jq '.DistributionConfig' > ${TEMPDIR}/orig.json
echo "${CONFIG}" | jq '.DistributionConfig | .DefaultCacheBehavior.LambdaFunctionAssociations.Items[0].LambdaFunctionARN= "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxx:function:test-func:3"' > ${TEMPDIR}/updated.json
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id CGSKSKLSLSM --distribution-config file://${TEMPDIR}/updated.json --if-match "${ETAG}"
```

Comment: You can't set the 0 index for the LambdaFunctionAssociations array. You need to update regarding the entrypoint of the lambda@edge

Answer (score 10):

Here is the script, that is doing exactly that. It is implemented based on @cloudbud answer. There is no argument checking. It would be executed like this: `./script QF234ASD342FG my-lambda-at-edge-function us-east-1`. In my case, the execution time is less than 10 sec. See [update-distribution](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html) for details.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -xeuo pipefail
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin

distribution_id="$1"
function_name="$2"
region="$3"

readonly lambda_arn=$(
  aws lambda list-versions-by-function \
    --function-name "$function_name" \
    --region "$region" \
    --query "max_by(Versions, &to_number(to_number(Version) || '0'))" \
  | jq -r '.FunctionArn'
)

readonly tmp1=$(mktemp)
readonly tmp2=$(mktemp)

aws cloudfront get-distribution-config \
  --id "$distribution_id" \
> "$tmp1"

readonly etag=$(jq -r '.ETag' < "$tmp1")

cat "$tmp1" \
| jq '(.DistributionConfig.CacheBehaviors.Items[] | select(.PathPattern=="dist/sxf/*") | .LambdaFunctionAssociations.Items[] | select(.EventType=="origin-request") | .LambdaFunctionARN ) |= "'"$lambda_arn"'"' \
| jq '.DistributionConfig' \
> "$tmp2"

# the dist config has to be in the file
# and be referred in specific way.
aws cloudfront update-distribution \
  --id "$distribution_id" \
  --distribution-config "file://$tmp2" \
  --if-match "$etag"

rm -f "$tmp1" "$tmp2"
```

Comment: very good, just need to adapt the path for myself (from .DistributionConfig.CacheBehaviors.Items[] to DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior) and everything worked like a charm. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

> could not figure out how to update the lambda arn only.

The link that you provided explains the process:

> The update process includes **getting the current distribution configuration**, updating the XML document that is returned to **make your changes**, and then submitting an UpdateDistribution request to **make the updates**.

This means that you can't just update lambda arn directly. You have:

1. Call [get-distribution-config](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/get-distribution-config.html) to obtain full current configuration.
2. Change the lambda arn in the configuration data obtained.
3. Upload the entire new configuration using [update-distribution](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html).

The process requires extra attention which is also explained in the docs [under](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html) **Warning**:

> You **must strip** out the ETag parameter that is returned.

> **Additional fields** are required when you update a distribution.

and more.

The process is indeed **complex**. Thus if you can I would recommend trying this on some **test/dummy** CloudFront distribution rather than directly on the production version.

Comment: what do you mean stripping the etag parameter?

Comment: @cloudbud Hi. Have you run the command? I'm unable to replicate your setup. Only you can test it as you have your distribution.

Comment: I have ran the commands and it updates the lambda function version, what do you mean. by strip the ETAG parameter?

Comment: @cloudbud That's what the linked instruction say. Maybe its not needed in your case if its working.

Comment: The distribution has been updated but i dont see the sme version as deployed when i check the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a Jenkins job to do this, I ended up with the following

```
#!groovy

def functionName = "<insert yours here>"
def versions = []

pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Resolve lambda versions') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withAWS(role: "${JENKINS_ROLE}", roleAccount: "${AWS_ACCOUNT}", region: "us-east-1") {
                        versions = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws lambda list-versions-by-function " +
                                "--function-name ${functionName} --query 'Versions[].Version' --output text").replaceAll('\\$LATEST', "")
                                .trim()
                                .split("\t")
                                .collect { it as int }
                                .sort()
                                .reverse()
                        echo "Versions found ${versions}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Update CloudFront distribution') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withAWS(role: "${JENKINS_ROLE}", roleAccount: "${AWS_ACCOUNT}", region: "us-east-1") {
                        def distributionId = "<insert yours here>"
                        def config = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                        def distributionConfig = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                        sh "aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id ${distributionId} > ${config}"
                        def etag = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat ${config} | jq -r .ETag").trim()
                        sh """
                            sed -i 's/\\("LambdaFunctionARN": \".*:${functionName}:\\)[^:]*\"/\\1${versions.first()}"/' ${config}
                        """
                        sh "cat ${config} | jq -r '.DistributionConfig' > ${distributionConfig}"
                        sh "aws cloudfront update-distribution --id ${distributionId} --if-match ${etag} --distribution-config file://${distributionConfig}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Remove old lambda versions') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withAWS(role: "${JENKINS_ROLE}", roleAccount: "${AWS_ACCOUNT}", region: "us-east-1") {
                        if (versions.size() < 3) {
                            echo "Not deleting any versions!"
                        } else {
                            versions[2..-1].each { version ->
                                sh "aws lambda delete-function --function-name ${functionName}:${version}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Last stage is optional, but it is generally a good idea not to pile up older lambda versions